# Add an item to the 'send to' menu for ALL users (win7)

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, user-profiles, send-to

I know there is the question [Add an item to the 'send to' menu for ALL users (winxp)](https://superuser.com/questions/23959/add-an-item-to-the-send-to-menu-for-all-users-winxp), but this does not work for Windows 7.

I already know how to add an item to the 'send to' menu of one user by dropping a shortcut file to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` (or more correctly, to the folder pointed by the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\SendTo`).

But it seems that there does not exist the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\SendTo` or similar key.

So is there any way to do this in windows 7?

Comment: Why did the solution from that topic not work? Did you get any errors?

Comment: @Rik the folder structure changed from windows XP to Vista

Comment: Yes you should use `copy "c:\Notepad.lnk" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo" /Y`.

Comment: Ooops sorry, I did saw so many answers that I thought that the one I linked was another. I did not like the proposed solution because it adds the script to the startup menu and it is visible by the user there. If a user happens to be administrator, it can remove it easily.

Comment: anyway, after more searching and not founding something as elegant as just dropping the shortcut into something like `C:\Users\All Users\SendTo`, I'll guess I'll have to go with the `bat` script. Thank you Rik and Peter King.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer #1: the solution you linked to in the other question does work, you need to adjust the script.

You put it into

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

and it needs to copy the file to the location you mentioned above:

```
copy "c:\Notepad.lnk" %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo /y
```

Answer #2: You can drop it in to any new users' folders automatically by putting it into

C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo

The Default profile is copied for each new user at creation.

Comment: Note: If answer #1 is used answer #2 does not need to be used. For new users the script will be executed too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are managing your computers / users with Group Policies, you can create a shortcut in the Send To folder.

Here are a couple write up on how to do that:

- [Adding shortcuts on desktop using Group Policy Preferences in Windows 8 and Windows 8.1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2014/02/17/adding-shortcuts-on-desktop-using-group-policy-preferences-in-windows-8-and-windows-8-1/)
- [How to Push Shortcuts to the Desktop With Group Policy](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-push-shortcuts-to-the-desktop-with-group-policy)

The only difference from the above write ups is to select "Send To" in the location option.